# How do I center a wx.MessageDialog to the frame?

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I've tried setting dlg.CenterOnParent() but that doesn't work. I assume it's because my MessageDialog is not setting the frame as the parent. In that case how would I do this?

Comment: Why can't you set the frame as the parent of the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a wx widget, the normal pattern of the create function is wx.SomeUIObject(parent, id, ...). The parent could be set when you create the dialog.